# Having trouble expressing a partial derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am new to this website and Mathematica, but I have a problem with partial derivatives. What i am trying to do is get the Lagrangian equation of my system using x,y coordinates. The problem is i think in the last part with T,L1,L2,L3 and L. The code is given here:

```
Clear[m, \[Alpha], \[Beta], l1, x, l3, l4, l5, L1, L2, L3, L, r]
n = 12;
l2 = 1;
m = 1;

f[\[Theta]_] := {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}
\[Alpha] = \[Alpha] /. Solve[(Pi - \[Alpha])*n == 2*Pi];
\[Beta] = (Pi - \[Alpha])/2;
l1 = 2*(Cos[\[Beta] ]/l2);
l3 = (l1*Cos[\[Beta] + \[Theta]])/Cos[Pi - \[Alpha]];
l4 = (l2*Cos[\[Theta]])/Cos[1/2*(Pi - \[Alpha])];
(*The calculation of the x coordinate of the whole system*)
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++ , x[i] = l3*Cos[((i - 1)*(Pi - \[Alpha]))];]
For[i = n + 1, i <= 2*n, i++ , 
 x[i] = l4*Cos[((i - 1/2)*(Pi - \[Alpha]))]]
l5 = l3 + 2*x[n + 1];
For[i = 2*n + 1, i <= 3*n, i++ , 
 x[i] = l5*Cos[((i - 1)*(Pi - \[Alpha]))]]

(*The calculation of the y coordinate of the whole system*)
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++ , y[i] = l3*Sin[((i - 1)*(Pi - \[Alpha]))]];
For[i = n + 1, i <= 2*n, i++ , 
  y[i] = l4*Sin[((i - 1/2)*(Pi - \[Alpha]))]];
For[i = 2*n + 1, i <= 3*n, i++ , 
  y[i] = l5*Sin[((i - 1)*(Pi - \[Alpha]))]];

(*The calculation of the velocity, the v here is v^2*)
For[i = 1, i <= 3*n, i++, v[i] = Dt[x[i]]^2 + Dt[y[i]]^2]
Simplify[v[2]];
Simplify[v[13]];
Simplify[v[25]];
(*Print["v",i,"=",Simplify[v[i]]*)

T = Simplify[Sum[1/2 m*Simplify[v[i]], {i, n*3}]];
L1 = Simplify[D[T, Dt[\[Theta]]]];
L2 = Dt[L1]
L3 = Simplify[[D[T, \[Theta]]]]
L = L2 - L3;
```

The answer is:
[image]

The problem is that the derivative of `Dt[\[Theta]]` should be a constant when deriving a derivative only with respect to `\[Theta]`. Furthermore, why is the r in `D[T, \[Theta]]` lighter blue than the `\[Theta]` at `L3 = Simplify[[D[T, \[Theta]]]]`?

The simplified example is given beneath:

```
f[r_] := {r, 0, 2*Pi}
a = r;
b = r^2;
F = a^2 + b^2;
F1 = Dt[F];
D[F1, r]
```

Where the answer is: 
    2 r !(*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), (r)](Dt[r])) + 4 r^3 !(*SubscriptBox[([PartialD]), (r)](Dt[r])) + 2 Dt[r] + 12 r^2 Dt[r]

Comment: I think that Dt[r] is not a constant because Mathematica doesn't know what "r" is. Indeed, r could also be a function of some other variable.
The fact that in a=r the r is blue it's because that's an undefined variable in the notebook, while in D[F1,r] "r" is an argument of the function.

Comment: In my problem r should be a variable that will very between 0 and 2pi.
If i add this:

f[r_] := {r, 0, 2*Pi}

It still doesn't work.

Comment: Please do not post images of your work. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. This will make it easier to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: @m_goldberg. I've added the code itself to the problem

Comment: I have a feeling that your code does not express what you are after (even if with errors), but something else. It may be a good idea, if you first write the expression you want to calculate in traditional mathematical notations. Than we will probably understand what's wrong with the Mathematica code.

Comment: Okay, i will change the example to the complete code that i am using. Maybe then the idea of what im trying to do is more clear.

Comment: In your simplified example you can say `D[F1, r] /. D[Dt[r], r] -> 0` if you want `Dt[r]` to be constant.  MMa will not assume it's constant unless you specify it.  I'm not really sure what answer you are looking for in your full problem, but maybe some similar specifications would work.

Comment: Thank you @BillWatts. With your input i fixed the problem. The problem was apparently not just Mathematica related. Other programmes have the same problem with symbolic differentiation of functions within functions. The answer was to add:

L3 = Simplify[D[T, \[Theta]] /. D[Dt[\[Theta]]] -> Constant]
L4 = Simplify[D[T, \[Theta]]]
L = Simplify[L2 - L3] /. Constant -> D[Dt[\[Theta]]]

Apperrently i needed a sort of substitution method so that the software can correctly differentiate the function. I also got the substituation idea at UT.